# Поиск по классу Python

Tags: python-3.x

У меня есть список, содержащий N классов с атрибутами.
Нужно вернуть из этого списка класс, в котором атрибут A равен нужному мне значению.
Как это правильно реализовать и более профессионально?

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста пример, который у вас есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class A: A = 'Hello, World!'
class B: A = 'Spam!'
class C: A = 'Eggs!'
class D: A = 'Ni!Ni!Ni!Ni!Ni!Ni!Ni!Ni!'

li = [A, B, C, D]

res = None
for x in li:
    if x.A == 'Spam!':  # 'Spam!' - это нужное мне значение
        res = x
        break

print(res)
```

*stdout:*

```
<class '__main__.B'>
```

Если Вы имели в виду экземпляры классов, то замените `li` на:

```py
li = [x() for x in (A, B, C, D)]
```